# How do you differentiate between an AJAX GET and an AJAX POST request in CakePHP?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

In my CakePHP app for my login method I do some different things for when a user submits a form via AJAX calls using `if ($this->request->is('ajax'))`

However I also want to allow the login method to be shown in a modal for quick login which again is an ajax call. But how do I detect the difference between the AJAX GET to show the form and then AJAX POST to do the actual login?

See below I can detect native get and posts but for ajax how do I detect the difference in CakePHP??? As it seems I can only detect an ajax event and not the type :/

```
NATIVE:

GET = if ($this->request->is('get'))
POST = if ($this->request->is('post'))


AJAX:

GET = if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
POST = if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
if ($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
            {
                echo json_encode('ajax get'); exit;
            }
            else {
                echo 'Normal get'; exit;
            }

        }

        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {   
            if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
            {
                echo json_encode('ajax post'); exit;
            }
            else {
                echo 'Normal post'; exit;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if the problem is that the form data can come in either as a POST or GET, the solution is to check whether the POST data is there. If it is, use POST, otherwise take the data from GET. (Or other way around.)

If the function should do different things depending on whether the form has been sent as POST or GET, then simply make two different functions in the controller.

Comment: Well basically if I load my form using ajax it will do the callbacks for posting the form. As ajax is just ajax. I want to detect the ajax post and ajax get methods.